# How to group items in one list based on consecutive elements in another list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a simple Data sorting problem:

I have two lists:

List1: `[1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5]` List2: `[objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD, ... objectI]`

The lists have the same length. I'd like to sort List2 into a nested List as follows:

List3: `[[objectA, objectB, objectC], [objectD], ...]`

So basically sort list2 to into sublists according to list1. Is this a list or a dictionary problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: show your minimal attempt (in functional code)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "list problem" or a "dictionary problem" in the real world. Your question is asking "how do I do this thing", so your title must reflect that. See [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. We're not here to write code for you. Try writing it yourself, but then if you get stuck, that could be a good opportunity for a question. See [ask]. If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: Also since this smells like homework: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Also note that there's no sorting involved here. Sorting means changing order. This keeps the order but makes groups.

Comment: Dudes, this is my first question on stack overflow ever - cut me some slack ^^. Not home work but personal project. Will be more precise with future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
from collections import Counter

list1=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4]
list2=["objectA", "objectB", "objectC", "objectD","objectE","objectF","objectG"]
to_dict=dict(Counter(list1).items()) #{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}

final=[]
i=0
for k,v in to_dict.items():
    final.append(list2[i:v+i])
    i+=v
```

**Output(final)**:

```
[
     ['objectA', 'objectB', 'objectC'],
     ['objectD', 'objectE'],
     ['objectF'],
     ['objectG']
]
```